# Finding the first position in a list that is over a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have the following list:

```
L = {2,4,6,8,10}
```

How can I get Mathematica to find the index position of the first value in the list that is over 4 (6 in this case). I tried `Position[L, L > 4]`, but this gave no output. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In version *10* there is a new function `FirstPosition`:

```
L = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

FirstPosition[ L, x_ /; x > 4]
```

> ```
> {3}
> ```

The second argument of `Position` as welll as of `FirstPosition` is a pattern, so this would yield what you seemed to expect:

```
Position[ L, x_ /; x > 4]
```

> ```
> {{3}, {4}, {5}}
> ```

Comment: Note that as given above, `FirstPosition` will apply at all levels (including the list as a whole) and at the list head: `FirstPosition[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, x_ /; (Print[x]; x > 12)]` prints `List`, `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`, `10`, `{2,4,6,8,10}`.  To get the expected behavior of only iterating over the list elements, you have to do something like `FirstPosition[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, x_ /; x > 12, Null, {1}, Heads -> False]` (or make the pattern more restrictive).

Answer (score 6):

Just for interest:

```
pos[lst_] := First@Position[lst, _?(# > 4 &)];
fp[lst_] := FirstPosition[lst, _?(# > 4 &)];
nw[lst_] := NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, lst[[#]] <= 4 &]
w[lst_] := Module[{n = 1}, While[lst[[n]] <= 4, n++]; n]
```

Comparing:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
bmp = Quiet@
  BenchmarkPlot[{pos, fp, nw, w}, RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, #] &, 
   PowerRange[10, 1000000], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: While this comparison is interesting I don't believe it   represents a correct picture of relative efficiency. Do you really belive that `NestWhile` or `While` are more efficient than `FirstPosition`?  I guess it is just an artefact of very special data you work with. In more general situation `FirstPosition` should be definitely faster, otherwise I can't see any argument for introducing this function to the system.

Comment: @Artes Currently for WRI the *verbosity* of the language is an argument for introducing new functions. In the view of this fact the comparisons like in this answer become especially valuable.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov As you might observe random long lists  out of a $21$-element set is very special choice which obviously rewards methods based on `NestWhile` or `While`. So it should be quite simple to point out different data where `FirstPosition` is much better even for long lists. This is what I meant in my former comment.

Comment: @Artes I'm not familiar with the notation $21$. What does it mean? Could you give an example where `FisrtPosition` has better performance than other methods?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  He's chosen `RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, n]` i.e. as a list it is of length $n$ (it may be whatever you want) but there are only $21$ different elements. If you played with e.g. long lists of primes with special properties and you were to choose a very special number then `FirstPosition` should be much better. I have no time to provide appropriate tests but I guess now it should be clear what I mean. I believe you can find a good example otherwise I'll try tomorow.

Comment: @Artes agree my answer naive and I do not explore in any meaningful way inputs...just curious after a long day at work in antipodes...

Answer (score 4):

```
L = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

f = 1 + LengthWhile[#, # <= 4 &] &;
(* or f = 1 + LengthWhile[#, Not[# > 4] &] &; *)
f@L
(* 3 *)
```

More generally,

```
f2 = Function[{lst, t}, 1 + LengthWhile[lst, Not[# > t] &]];
f2[L, 4]
(* 3 *)
```