# First position of incremental series

Tags: function-construction

I am still a beginner and maybe I want to do something too complicate!

After 29 cycles I obtained the following events list:
`L={0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,4}`. The first time the events 1,2,3 and 4 manifest, are at the 3rd,10th,15th and 29th cycle, respectively. I would like to cut the cycle series:

```
CL={{0,0,1},{0,1,1,1,1,1,2},{2,1,1,2,3},{2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,4}}
```

and automate the first event search to obtain the following list:

```
EL={3,10,15,29}
```

I am so far only able to get the first elements by using:

```
cyclefinder=TakeWhile[L, # < 1 &]
eventfinder=FirstPosition[L, x_ /; x = 1]
```

I have already searched in previous answers (pe. [Finding the first position in a list that is over a certain value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64779/finding-the-first-position-in-a-list-that-is-over-a-certain-value/64782#64782)), but maybe you can help me to find the right one, because in my serie the value is incremental. 
Thank you! 
LXXX

Comment: You can obtain `EL` with `Table[FirstPosition[L, k], {k, 4}] // Flatten`.

Comment: To expand on J.M.'s answer, here is how you can get CL once you have computed EL:

`Map[Take[L, #]& ,Rest[FoldList[{#1[[2]] + 1, #2}&, {0, 0}, Sort[Union[EL, {Length[L]}]]]] ]`

There may be a more efficient way to do this, but it is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Hallo J.M. and C.Woods! Thank you for your answers! Your commands work very well! My task for today is to tray to make a function out of them, because theoretically the cycles I can get are infinite! I will tell you if I make it!

Comment: Ok! I got the first: `eventfinder[r_] := 
 Table[FirstPosition[#, n], {n, 1, r, 1}] & /@ {L} // Flatten`